# How to check if $f(x, y) = (x + y^2, 2xy, y + 2x^3)$ is an injective map, where $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^3$? Are polynomial maps proper?

Tags: functions, differential-topology

I'm trying to check whether the following map $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^3$ is an embedding.

$$f(x, y) = (x + y^2, 2xy, y + 2x^3)$$

It's easy to see that this is an immersion because the columns of the Jacobian

$$df_{(x, y)} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 2y \\ 2y & 2x \\ 6x^2 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

are not linearly dependent in general and hence the kernel must be $\{0\}$.

However, I'm stuck at checking whether $f(x, y)$ is injective as I don't see an easy way to construct an inverse function.

Also, is there an easy way to conclude that $f(x, y)$ is a proper map? I think it should be proper as it involves polynomials but is there a rigorous theorem about this? (Embedding = Immersion + Injective + Proper)

**Edit:** This is not a homework problem. I'm trying to prepare for an exam and this is a practice problem. Let me provide my attempt in brief: If $x + y^2 = a$, $2xy = b$, and $y + 2x^3 = c$, I do not see a straightforward way to solve for $x$ and $y$. There also doesn't seem to be any kind of symmetry that would me to directly conclude non-injectivity.

Comment: I suspect that there is no general theorem about polynomials leading to proper maps. Consider just $(x, y) \mapsto xy$. (This is a map $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$.) The preimage of $\{0\}$ is not compact. Edit: Maybe it can be salvaged if the function is injective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not injective. Consider $f(x,0) = (x, 0, 2x^3)$ and $f(0,y) = (y^2, 0, y)$. One can check that there is a solution in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to the system of equations
\begin{cases}
  x = y^2 \\
  2x^3 = y
\end{cases}
where $x$ and $y$ are not both $0$.